# Pivot certain rows within a data frame into columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data set that looks like the following:

```r
data
# A tibble: 12 × 3
    Number Letter      Identifier   
    <chr>  <chr>       <chr>
  1 1      A           AB   
  2 2      B           BC   
  3 <NA>   <NA>        <NA> 
  4 Site   Bow River   <NA> 
  5 Date   2020-06-01  <NA> 
  6 <NA>   <NA>        <NA> 
  7 Number Letter      Identifier   
  8 3      C           CD   
  9 4      D           DE   
 10 <NA>   <NA>        <NA> 
 11 Site   Elbow River <NA> 
 12 Date   2019-05-01  <NA>
```

I want to be able to subset and pivot the rows with `Site` and `Date` into columns and fill downwards in order to get it to look like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Number Letter Identifer Site        Date      
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>     
1 1      A      AB        Bow River   2020-06-01
2 2      B      BC        Bow River   2020-06-01
3 3      C      CD        Elbow River 2019-05-01
4 4      D      DE        Elbow River 2019-05-01
```

I had no luck using `pivot_longer` or `pivot_wider` since those rows with `Site` and `Date` are in the middle of the data set and separating it in two.

I'm mostly familiar with dplyr code but tried to use base R to do it as well with no luck.

Sorry about the formatting, it's my first time posting to Stack.

Here's the reprex:

```
data <- tibble::tribble(~Number, ~Letter, ~Identifer, 
                "1", "A", "AB",
                "2", "B", "BC",
                NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
                "Site", "Bow River", NA_character_,
                "Date", "2020-06-01", NA_character_,
                NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
                "Number", "Letter", "Identifier",
                "3", "C", "CD",
                "4", "D", "DE",
                NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
                "Site", "Elbow River", NA_character_,
                "Date", "2020-05-01", NA_character_)
```

Comment: This might be able to be dealt with at the import stage. I am guessing that this has been read in from a text file which has multiple chunks of data repeating every 6 or 7 lines?

Comment: @thelatemail no, this is from an excel sheet xlsx file. The data was just entered really poorly, with the information on site and date under the rest of the data and repeated for each segment of data within the same sheet. I have multiple excel files to clean with the same formatting, so dealing with it at the cleaning stage is my best bet I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way, probably could be made more concise.

I'm using each occasion where it says `Number` in the `Number` column as a delimiter for a new group, and using that to define the fill range for values put into the `Site` and `Date` columns.

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  mutate(Site = if_else(Number == "Site", Letter, NA_character_),
         Date = if_else(Number == "Date", Letter, NA_character_),
         group = cumsum(coalesce(Number == "Number", 0))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  fill(Site, Date, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!is.na(Identifer), Number != "Number") %>% 
  select(-group)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Number Letter Identifer Site        Date      
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>     
1 1      A      AB        Bow River   2020-06-01
2 2      B      BC        Bow River   2020-06-01
3 3      C      CD        Elbow River 2020-05-01
4 4      D      DE        Elbow River 2020-05-01
```